# Show that a (not identically zero) billinear map $T: E \times F \rightarrow G$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $E,F,G$ be normed spaces, and let $T:E\times F \rightarrow G$ be a bilinear map (not indentically zero). Show that T is not uniformly continuous.
As usual, we are using the product norm $\lvert\lvert \cdot \rvert\rvert_{E\times F} = \textrm{max}\{\lvert\lvert \cdot \rvert\rvert_E, \lvert\lvert \cdot \rvert\rvert_F\}$.

I know this follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem, but it's an introduction to an undergrad class, so we are not allowed to use such results.

Comment: But $T(x,y) = x+y$ is not a bilinear map.
$T(x_1 + x_2, y) = x_1 + x_2 + y \neq (x_1+y)+(x_2+y) = T(x_1,y) + T(x_2,y)$

Comment: Yes , you are right, Matheus, but still, the statement seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @azif00 How did you get this inequality?

Comment: @azif00 But this does not make it uniformly continuous since $||(x,y)||_{E \times F}$ cannot be uniformly approximated by $||x||_E \cdot ||y||_F$. For example $T(x,y) = xy$ is not unifromly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets You're right, my mistake. Let me delete my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will first reduce the problem to a nonzero bilinear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Take any $x \in E$ and $y \in F$ such that $T(x,y) = z$ for some $0 \neq z \in G$ and consider the subspaces $A = \operatorname{span} \{x\} \times \operatorname{span} \{y\}$ of $E  \times F$, and $B = \operatorname{span} z$ of $G$. Now just identify $A$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B$ with $\mathbb{R}$ and consider the restriction of $T$ on $A$ with range in $B$. If we show that this restriction is not uniformly continuous, then so cannot be the original map $T$.

So it remains to show that any nonzero bilinear map $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous. Note that any such map is of the form $T(x,y) = c \cdot xy$ for some nonzero constant $c$ (just take $c = T(1,1)$). It is now an easy excercise to show that this $T$ is not unifromly continuous.